# Select multiple columns with single alias

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

What's the alternate to

```
select table_name.* as colAlias from table_name
```

I assume this used to work pre 5.5 MySQL.

Comment: i don't get the point of combining multiple columns into one alias. could you elaborate?

Comment: You want to concatenate them? `SELECT CONCAT_WS(','col1, col2, col3) AS thealias`

Comment: actually, the problem is, it is a maintainance project. It was developed long back and when I upgrade the db to 5.5 MySql I got some exception around this query. So looking for an alternative instead of digging into the huge stuff which I am not aware of ! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1,', ',col2,', ',col3) AS cols
    FROM table_name ORDER BY cols;
```

or also

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1,' ',col2,' ',col3) AS cols
    FROM table_name ORDER BY cols;
```

Comment: What does the ',' between column names for?

Comment: @WhiteBig Its comma delimiter. .